# Second video card for virtual machine with PCI passthrough

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, pci-passthrough

I am very new to the PCI passthrough topic. 
So could you explain some things to me.
I have a System with Ryzen 5 1600 and GTX 1060 6GB. I also have a secondary PCIe slot and an old Radeon HD 5700. So could I just put that second card into the PCIe slot and then use it with PCI passthrough in a Virtual Machine? Am I right with that or are there any things I need? And are there good tutorials how to do that then?

Comment: If you're expecting this to work with Virtualbox, then you're going to be disappointed. QEM/KVM can do this - and very well. Here's a link to how to setup a Windows 10 VM with GPU passthrough: https://blog.zerosector.io/2018/07/28/kvm-qemu-windows-10-gpu-passthrough/